# Why does this code for creating a Python log not work?

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to get the Python logging module to work:

The code:

```
import logging
import os

LOG_FILENAME = os.path.join(r'D:\MPhil\Model_Building\Models\Exercises\MCMC\MCMC_in_python\AtoB','CopasiMC.log')
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.DEBUG,filemode='w')
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
```

Doesn't do anything. My goal  is to use this code in a `if __name__=='__main__:'` block then use this log to document code progress as I write a set of python  classes. Can anybody tell me why this isn't working.

Comment: Could not replicate, I get a log file in the specified directory.

Comment: It works for me as expected. The file `CopasiMC.log` is created, and the message *"This message should go to the log file"* stored. Are you sure the given path exists, and that you have permission to write to it? Try creating the log file in a root, like `C:`.

Comment: Are you making any other logging calls before you call `basicConfig`? According to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig), if there's a root handler already configured, it won't do anything.

Comment: The directory definitely exists and I definitely have access to write to it. I was trying this under a main block but I've just tried it in a new python script (with a new iPython shell) and I still do not get any output. Very strange.

Comment: Could it be that you put the logging code inside `__name__=='__main__'` block, yet you are importing the module from somewhere, in which case the if will not hold?

Comment: Unfortunately no, since I am now executing the same code from a new script with only the above code.

Comment: Could you please try writing to the current working directory? Just replace the path with a single dot. `os.path.join(r'.','CopasiMC.log')`

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions everyone. @skreborn But still no output.

Comment: I'd inspect the contents of `logging.root.level` and `logging.root.handlers` and see if it's getting your configuration.

Comment: This code works on my machine. I can even Log the debug outputs ! although I am using Ubuntu I replaced your Path to `r'.'` and the log file gets created and I can log data in `main()` function too

Comment: Are you using this from a Jupyter Notebook or IPython window? Some behavior is found to be different in those environments.